# How to convert Cordova Android app to iOS?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I have developed the Android app with HTML5,CSS and Javascript using Cordova.

In this I have used some native plugins like geolocation etc.

I want to convert this app to iOS.

Will the app directly be converted to iOS without changing any code?

What should I do?

I know there is Phonegap build services but I have not used Phonegap to develop the app.

I do not have a Mac machine.

Thanks,

Comment: you have mentioned that you have used *cordova* and then at last you mentioned not used *phonegap* ? it is bit confusing. have you created *cordova* project with adding platform ?

Comment: Sorry not mentioned, I have used Cordova command line not Phonegap

Comment: You for sure need *mac machine* else you need to use *VM ware* and install *mac* to that and use it.

Comment: Will there be any change in code for IOS?

Comment: It depends on your functionalities which you have used. and also based on what plugins you have used in some case.

Comment: You have to build app using command line for ios and need mac machine for that.

Comment: You need MAC machine and further changes depends on testing app in iOS device. Check for plugin that it is available for iOS platform too.

Answer (score -1):

```
    Ext.application({
    viewport: {
        autoBlurInput: false
    },
    name:'MyApp',
    controllers:[],
    stores:[],
    models:[],
    views:[],
    launch:function(){
        Ext.Msg.defaultAllowedConfig.showAnimation = false;
         if (Ext.os.is.Android) {
            Ext.Viewport.on('painted', function () {
                Ext.Viewport.setHeight(window.innerHeight);
            });
        }
        Ext.Viewport.add(Ext.create('MyApp.view.LoginView'));
    }
});
Ext.define('Override.util.PaintMonitor', {
    override: 'Ext.util.PaintMonitor',
    constructor: function (config) {
        return new Ext.util.paintmonitor.CssAnimation(config);
    }
});
Ext.define('Override.util.SizeMonitor', {
    override: 'Ext.util.SizeMonitor',
    constructor: function (config) {
        var namespace = Ext.util.sizemonitor;

        if (Ext.browser.is.Firefox) {
            return new namespace.OverflowChange(config);
        } else if (Ext.browser.is.WebKit || Ext.browser.is.IE11) {
            return new namespace.Scroll(config);
        } else {
            return new namespace.Default(config);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi Parth Patel, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Could you add some context to your answer, explaining how this will help the questioner solve their problem?